# How to obtain Grothendieck’s “Long March Through Galois Theory”

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, galois-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Several works cite "La longue marche a travers la theorie de galois". The work by Leila Schneps "Grothendieck’s "Long March through Galois theory" ( http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/SchnepsLM.pdf ) tells us that there is as TeX format of the Long March.

I have looked on the Internet, and was able only to find the repository grothendieckcircle. It has only the part B of the first part of the work ( http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/LM/LMIb.pdf ). In the libraries the manuscript seems to be only available on the bookshelves of several University libraries. Neither Amazon, or other online stores has the manuscript.

Does anyone know if there are scans of the work on the Internet? Or maybe someone has a digital copy of the published work?

Comment: You can try contacting Jean Malgoire at Montpellier, as written in a note of the first pdf you link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[La Longue Marche, Table des Matieres](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/%7Eleila/grothendieckcircle/LM/tableLM.pdf).

[Github project to (TeX)-type a scanned copy of "La longue Marche, Ia #1-25](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/galois.pdf).

[La Longue Marche, Ib #26-37](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/LM/LMIb.pdf).

The first part is already complete. #1-37

---

**Edit:** *There has been some changes in the same [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219822/grothendiecks-la-longue-marche-%C3%A0-travers-la-th%C3%A9orie-de-galois) question! Namely, a project for [typing it](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/galois.pdf).*

Answer (score 8):

After digging through tones of Internet material, I have answered my own question: currently, as of August 3, 2015, there is no resource on the Internet that contains all of the work "La longue marche à travers la théorie de Galois". Not scanned, not in TeX, not in PDF. There is only that which has been made available by Leila Schneps.

"Long March Through Galois Theory" can either be obtained from Jean Malgoire directly, or from a university library, or from the Université de Montpellier (there are reportedly some 20,000 pages of material from Grothendieck stored somewhere in a box).

An interesting resource I found is the archived web page of Malgoire: https://web.archive.org/web/20070211071321/http://www.math.univ-montp2.fr/agata/malgoire.html . It's in French, but you can use Google translate. Basically it states that he has all of the work, and that he is working on retyping it in TeX and publishing it.

---

**Edit:** As of 2020, all pages of the manuscript are scanned at Montpellier's University and available online at [Archives Grothendieck](https://grothendieck.umontpellier.fr/archives-grothendieck).

Comment: There is no date on your last link, but it's worth noting that it's very old: it still uses French francs as a currency (replaced by the euro in 1999)! The situation has most certainly changed since then.